# Java gRPC Custom Client-side load balancing

Tags: java, grpc, load-balancing, multi-tenant

I write a Java app using gRPC. As I looked in documentation: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md

and in blog: https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing

there are some available gRPC
Application level client side load balancers:

- grpclb
- pick_first
- round_robin

None of them fit my needs. I need to implement a custom one.
Problem is that I cannot find how to do it - not in documentation nor in google search/stackoverflow.

In App each server serves a couple of tenants. When new tenant created and max limit of tenant per server is  reached - need to start new server.

I see here 2 problems I need to solve:

1. When new server starts dynamically - how can I add new http/2 connection from client to this server(as I understand - it means to add new subchannel) ?
2. I need to point each request to proper server by tenant name it serves. I can implement in code server registry to be aware what servers up and what tenants each of them serves.
   But main questions are

- how can I implement custom request balancing?
- What class I need to implement/override to supply dynamically server IP to point to for each request?

Answer (score 0):

In grpc-java, you can implement a custom [`io.grpc.LoadBalancer`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/LoadBalancer.html). It controls which subchannels (connection to server) are created and chooses which subchannel to use for each request. They are advanced, and don't have examples. There is documentation, but you probably will want to look at the [RoundRobinLoadBalancer implementation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/util/RoundRobinLoadBalancer.java).

To direct individual requests, the client application can attach the tenant ID as Metadata (with an interceptor) or using custom CallOptions, which are [available on the stub](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/AbstractStub.html#withOption-io.grpc.CallOptions.Key-T-). Then within your `LoadBalancer.Picker` you'd read that ID from the [`LoadBalancer.pickSubchannelArgs`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/LoadBalancer.PickSubchannelArgs.html).

Normally addresses are discovered using [NameResolver](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/NameResolver.html), but in your case it may be more appropriate for the LoadBalancer to directly call any remote service to look up the addresses. This is actually what is done in grpclb.

Comment: Thank you @Eric. I looked at RoundRobinLoadBalancer - it is complicated a little. I will need some time to understand a flow. What is the Picker lifecycle? Does new instance need to be created in each call of updateBalancingState(actual change of active subchannel list)?

Comment: You can re-use a Picker instance, but generally it is a new instance each time which holds the picking state. Pickers are called each RPC so need to be fast and have minimal logic. When you call updateBalancingState() it tells gRPC that something may have changed, so it will loop through all queued RPCs and see if the Picker returns a subchannel.