# How to configure client-side load balancing with grpc-java

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I've seen some high-level information about load balancing, but am struggling to put the pieces together. Here's what I've reviewed:

- [Load Balancing in gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md) (gRPC GitHub)
- [gRPC Load Balancing](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing/) (gRPC blog)
- [gRPC on HTTP/2 Engineering a Robust, High-performance Protocol](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-on-http2/) (gRPC blog)
- [gRPC client-side load balancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/loadbalancing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#write-custom-resolvers-and-load-balancers) (Microsoft guide)
- [Java gRPC Custom Client-side load balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510984/java-grpc-custom-client-side-load-balancing) (Stack Overflow)

Obviously the core pieces are a resolver and a load balancer. My use case is that I have several static, known addresses. I simply want to prioritize them as primary, secondary, etc. I believe the `pick_first` policy will work for this.

What I can't figure out is how to set up a custom NameResolver. I've defined a custom NameResolverProvider:

```
public class StaticResolverProvider extends NameResolverProvider {

    @Value("${tls.enabled}")
    private boolean isTlsEnabled;

    @Override
    protected boolean isAvailable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected int priority() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public NameResolver newNameResolver(URI targetUri, Args args) {
        return new StaticResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultScheme() {
        return isTlsEnabled ? "https" : "http";
    }
}
```

and (hopefully) registered it while creating my Channel:

```
new NameResolverRegistry().register(new StaticResolverProvider());
```

Finally, here is the (currently unimplemented) NameResolver:

```
public class StaticResolver extends NameResolver {

    @Override
    public String getServiceAuthority() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
    }
}
```

These are the only two methods I see that need to be implemented. Neither of these seem to have anything to do with returning an ordered list of known addresses. The `getServiceAuthority()` mentions authentication, which confuses me because I don't know what the NameResolver has to do with authentication.

Please advise on what I'm missing. Thanks!

---

## Update

I figured out the Name Resolver piece. First off, registering my resolver with my Channel looked a little different:

```java
NameResolverRegistry.getDefaultRegistry().register(new StaticResolverProvider());
```

In my NameResolverProvider, I updated the `getDefaultScheme()` method to return "customScheme", which is the piece that would link it to my channel's call to `forTarget()`.

The final piece was to implement the `refresh()` method in my NameResolver:

```java
@Override
public void refresh() {
    ResolutionResult.Builder resolutionResultBuilder = ResolutionResult.newBuilder();
    List<EquivalentAddressGroup> servers = new ArrayList<>();
    servers.add(new EquivalentAddressGroup(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50055)));
    servers.add(new EquivalentAddressGroup(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 50056)));
    resolutionResultBuilder.setAddresses(Collections.unmodifiableList(servers));
    listener.onResult(resolutionResultBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These are the only two methods I see that need to be implemented.

Those are the abstract ones. But the main one you need to implement is `refresh()` which is defined as no-op but needs to be overridden in your implementation to do anything useful. You can look at [UdsNameResolver](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/UdsNameResolver.java) to see how `refresh()` is implemented and follow that pattern.

> The getServiceAuthority() mentions authentication

You can ignore that for your use-case.